# Convert CURL to URLRequest

Tags: ios, swift, curl, urlrequest, urlsession

I’m trying to converting the the following curl request Swagger gives me to URLRequest:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 
--header 'Authorization: key ttn-account-v2.<app-key>'
 'https://<app-id>.data.thethingsnetwork.org/api/v2/query'
```

URL and Headers are set correctly. Still I get the response: 401 - Not authorized.

```
let key = "ttn-account-v2.<app-key>"

let url = URL(string: "https://<app-id>.data.thethingsnetwork.org/api/v2/query")

var request = URLRequest(url: url!)

request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
request.addValue("key \(key)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
    guard error == nil else {
        print(error!)
        return
    }
    guard let data = data else {
        print("Data is empty")
        return
    }

    let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    print(json)
}
task.resume()
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: are you sure that key header is correct? check if it does not send it as Optional(...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is going wrong is that you create a perfect request but then skip it all together by doing a `dataTask` with just the url and not the request. This way the `HTTPHeaders` aren't send with the request, thus it is not authorised. 
Just change the task creation line to this:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: req) { data, response, error in 
    ...
}
```